# Google signin - not working in production

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-signin

Google sign in works when testing on the emulator and a real device, however, in production it doesn't work. I have added the SHA 1 key to my Firestore project.

How would I fix this?

```
Future<User> googleSignIn() async {
    try {
      GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await Global.googleSignIn.signIn();
      GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
          await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );
      UserCredential result = await Global.fbAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
      User user = result.user;
      updateUserData(user);
      return user;
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

```
        onPressed: () async {
        showDialogue(context);
          var user = await loginMethod();
          if (user != null) {
            hideProgressDialogue(context);
            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, SharedStrings.userInfoPath);
```

```
signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }

       buildTypes {
       release {
           // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
           // Signing with the debug keys for now,
           // so `flutter run --release` works.
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
```

Comment: You mean to say when application is live on play or app store ?

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede Yeah, my app's just been published and now Google sign in is not working

Comment: In what way does it not work? Do you get an error message?

Comment: @DrSatan1 After selecting the email address it just stayed on loading

Comment: I think you need to add Play console SHA 1 key 
Go to Play console Select Your app -> Setup -> App signing 
and add this SHA1 key to your firebase account

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede Do I replace the existing key in my firebase project with this new key?

Comment: no no, Only add one more key don't replace @SK7

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede Ok cool i've added it and now need to upload a new version to see if it's worked. You can add your comment as an answer if you like and I'll accept it.

Comment: @SK7 yes before upload the new version please check the existing APK may be it will work now or else go for upload new version

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede I just checked and on my phone it went straight into the app without checking which email and on another phone it still stayed on loading

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede So it went straight into the app without asking for the password for the google account

Comment: @SK7 right, When you use google sign then they do not ask you password. You only need to select gmail account also please share app link or name if possible

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede Ah ok I see. Sure, here's the link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.planetrescue_climatechange

Answer (score 5):

After Uploading to play store, Play store generate its own SH1 which we have to replace in second key in google console.

Go to google console>app signing> copy SH1 generate by console. Add that in google sign in console replace it from 2nd key.

[image]

Comment: ahmed bajwa you are super you solve my problem